# Perl: installing with Perlbrew on Macos Sierra

Tags: perl, macos-sierra, perlbrew

I am attempting to use the lastest version of Perlbrew to install the latest stable version of Perl (5.24.1) with multi-threading on a computer running macOS-Sierra.

Perlbrew appears to be installed correctly but when I run the command:

```
Perlbrew install perl-5.24.1 --thread or
perlbrew install stable --thread
```

The installation proceeds but then fails with the following message

```
Installation process failed. To spot any issues, check

  /Users/alan/perl5/perlbrew/build.perl-5.24.1.log

If some perl tests failed and you still want to install this distribution anyway,
do:

  (cd /Users/alan/perl5/perlbrew/build/perl-5.24.1; make install)

You might also want to try upgrading patchperl before trying again:
```

Looking at the log file as suggested above I find the following error messages at the end of the file:

```
1 error generated.
make[1]: *** [HiRes.o] Error 1
cc -c   -fno-common -DPERL_DARWIN -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack- protector-strong -I/usr/local/include -Wall -Werror=declaration-after-statement -Wextra -Wc++-compat -Wwrite-strings -Wthread-safety -O3 -DVERSION=\"1.9733\" -DXS_VERSION=\"1.9733\"  "-I../.."  -DTIME_HIRES_NANOSLEEP -DTIME_HIRES_CLOCK_GETTIME -DTIME_HIRES_CLOCK_GETRES -DTIME_HIRES_CLOCK_NANOSLEEP -DTIME_HIRES_CLOCK -DTIME_HIRES_STAT=1 -DATLEASTFIVEOHOHFIVE HiRes.c
HiRes.xs:945:15: error: use of undeclared identifier 'darwin_time_mutex'
MUTEX_INIT(&darwin_time_mutex);
          ^
1 error generated.
make[1]: *** [HiRes.o] Error 1
Unsuccessful make(dist/Time-HiRes): code=512 at make_ext.pl line 569.
make: *** [lib/auto/Time/HiRes/HiRes.bundle] Error 25
##### Brew Failed #####"
```

At other points in the log file, the following message appears several times too (although I have no idea how relevant this is to the failed installation process):

```
ld: warning: object file (xxxxxxxx) was built for newer OSX version (10.12) than being linked (10.4)
```

I have searched for similar problems on the web and found nothing close. I therefore wondering if this is a general issue with Perlbrew and Sierra or whether it is specific to my setup.

Obviously I am beginner at programming and programming in Perl especially so please keep any responses as simple as possible

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3):

You are not the only one: it's a bug. See [Bug #128972 for perl5: Build failure on OS X 10.12 Sierra](https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=128972)

It seems that the bug is solved for 5.26.0, but not (yet) back-ported to 5.24.2 and 5.22.4.

You could try with the bleeding-edge version (but that could very well have other problems):

```
perlbrew install perl-blead
```

Comment: While this is technically correct, there is no 5.26.0 yet. The most current dev release at the moment is 5.25.9. We don't know if the patch will still be there in 5.26.0.

Comment: Sorry I did some typing errors. As far as I can remember it should be fixed in 5.24.2

Comment: It's fixed in blead (the future 5.26.0), which is not the same as 5.24.2. According to that ticket, the fix has not been backported to the 5.24 branch, which is why ikegami edited your answer; "the bug is solved for the not yet released 5.24.2" is not true.

Comment: @ikegami Sorry I edited my post without seeing your edits. I reverted my last edit.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you all for your help